# select * from '%_BT'.dbo.Version

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 database instance for a cloud product that I manage  product versions for.

We format the use is

```
customername_bt
customername_bs
```

where `[_bt]` is product 1 and `[_bs]` is product 2.  I realise I can hard code then union a query like so;

```
select * from cust1_bt.dbo.version union
select * from cust1_bs.dbo.version union
select * from cust2_bt.dbo.version union
select * from cust2_bs.dbo.version
```

However, every time a new customer is added I'd have to revisit the query which adds an element of human error therefore, I'm wondering if I can achieve this result another way.

Obvious this isn't a thing but hopefully it drives what I'm hoping to achieve home

```
select * from '%_bt'.dbo.Version UNION
select * from '%_bs'.dbo.Version
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have an error in your database design. You should not create one table per customer. Create a single table, make the customer ID a column in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @SQLText VARCHAR(MAX) =''

select @SQLText  = @SQLText  + 'UNION select * from ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.dbo.Version ' 
from sys.databases WHERE 
   name like '%[_]bt' 
   or name like '%[_]bs' 

SET @SQLText = STUFF(@SQLText,1,6,'')

EXEC @SQLText
```

Comment: Thanks Serkan, I understand what's going on here, unfortunately I get an error message

"Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 13
The name 'select * from XXX.dbo.Version UNION select * from XXX.dbo.Version UNION select * from XXX.dbo.Version UNION select * from XXX.dbo.Version UNION select * from XXX.dbo.Version UNION select * from XXX.dbo.Version UNION select * from XXX.dbo.Version UNION select creationda' is not a valid identifier."

I omitted the database names on purpose, any thoughts?